# export default inferring takes shortcut

Tags: typescript

In a default export, if the expression is solely a variable identifier, the inferrer takes the declaration of the variable as an imho non-permissible shortcut, instead of the type of the expression.

Is this a bug, or intended behavior?

```
// b.ts
const v: string | number = 0;
export default v;
// working alternatives:
// export default (v);
// export default v as typeof v;

// a.ts
import v from './b';
v.toFixed(2); // error
```

Inferring the type of the expression can be forced by various means, as seen above.

---

While the above should be sufficient by itself, here is some more context, also to avoid XY-problems. I noticed it, when trying to merge a symbol onto a function:

```
// b.ts
const sy = Symbol();
const merge: <F extends (...args: any) => any>(f: F) => asserts f is F & { [sy]: string }
  = f => (f as any)[sy] = 'something';
const f = () => {};
merge(f);
export default f; // gives original type
```

A work-around would be `export default Object.assign(f, { [sy]: 'something' });`, but an inlined assignment should be preferable, and what a javascript equivalent would do. Note, that above code has another issue, when re-exporting the import, but i inquire about that in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66926796/exported-variable-cannot-be-named-error-with-symbol) (also feels like a bug, but i am not sure).

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's a bug since the alternatives that work should be completely identical in their effect but they are not.

Comment: I am thinking the same, but am careful with jumping to conclusions, because i don't fully understand every aspect.